# EXCEL VBA: Web Page Button Click

Tags: excel, vba, web

I have tried numerous variations of codes on this site to get my VBA to click on a button on a webpage and with the exception of one time have not been able to get any code to work.  The one time was either a fluke or in an attempt to add the next step of the code I somehow inadvertently changed what was happening previously. Below is both the source code of the website and the code I'm using currently.  Right now I do not get any errors, but instead of loading the next page when I include the button click code if just clears the form and stays on the present web page.

CODE:

```
Public Sub TestIE()
Dim IE As Object
Dim aNodeList As Object, i As Long
Dim bNodeList As Object, p As Long


' Create InternetExplorer Object
Set IE = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")

' You can uncoment Next line To see form results
IE.Visible = False

' Send the form data To URL As POST binary request
IE.Navigate "https://pe.fanniemae.com/pe/pricing/search"

' Statusbar
Application.StatusBar = "Page is loading. Please wait..."

' Wait while IE loading...
Do While IE.Busy
Application.Wait DateAdd("s", 1, Now)
Loop

IE.Visible = True

Set aNodeList = IE.document.querySelectorAll("input[type=checkbox]")
If aNodeList Is Nothing Then Exit Sub
For i = 0 To 18
aNodeList.Item(i).Checked = True
Next i


'IE.document.querySelector("button[type=submit]").Click

Set bNodeList = IE.document.querySelectorAll("button[type=submit]")
If bNodeList Is Nothing Then Exit Sub
For p = 1 To 1
bNodeList.Item(p).Click
Next p

End Sub
```

Page Source:

```
<div class="row submit">
        <button id="get-price" tabindex="3" type="submit" class="cell-right- 
         2">Get Prices</button>
        <div class="pricing-error-message"></div>
```

When I inspect element on the button it does appear there is a clear form part of the code, which I would expect, but for whatever reason it is clearing the form instead of loading the new page.  When I click on the button manually in IE it loads as expected.

Script that I believe is running:

```
  <script type="text/javascript">
    define('pageConf', function() {

        return null || JSON.parse('{\"lastPricingFactors\": 

 {\"priceIncrement\":\"18\",\"priceView\":\"total\",\"executionType\
 ":\"Mandatory\",\"levelType\":\"Product\",\"remittanceType\":\"ActualActual
 \",\"products\":\"160958\",\"1036FR\",\"102422\",\"163053\",\"160639\",\"
160058\",\"155509\",\"154232\",\"143846\",\"0005FR\",\"125331\",\"102301\",
\"114921\",\"115446\",\"144854\"],\"underwrittenWithDu\":false,\"
servicingReleased\":false,\"displayMarketFrozenMessage\":false,\"windows\":
[10,30,60,90],\"requestTimeMs\":1531424470700}}')
    });

    </script>
```

Comment: Take a look at Selenium WebDriver for VBA. A nice post about it: https://codingislove.com/browser-automation-in-excel-selenium/

Comment: Are you sure this is the right element to click? Is there any javascript associated? You may need to use F12 and look for event listeners and possibly there is something else that needs to happen to ensure entered values are actually entered/retained.

Comment: Fairly sure it is the right element, there is only 2 buttons on the screen.  The other button clicks fine using this method so something else is likely going on as you suggested.  I don't know enough about java to know if there is some associated.  When I right click and inspect element there is a portion of code that mentions clearing the form, which I would expect when navigating away from the page, but it doesnt seem to be taking that next step of actually moving.  Is there any portion of the code that I could paste in that may help someone smarter than myself?

Comment: Added possibly relevant script above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to utilize a Select Case that inserted the criteria I wanted selected in the URL that was generated by the button vs. having to actually press the button which seems to be a working work around.  Thanks for taking a look at this.